# Как решить данную ошибку?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Установил плагин и когда активировал такая ошибка

```
Uncaught RuntimeException: Error saving action: Error saving action: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\wp-content\plugins\wpforms-lite\vendor\woocommerce\action-scheduler\classes\migration\ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php:44 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\wp-content\plugins\wpforms-lite\vendor\woocommerce\action-scheduler\classes\data-stores\ActionScheduler_HybridStore.php(242): ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator->save_action(Object(ActionScheduler_Action), NULL) #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\wp-content\plugins\wpforms-lite\vendor\woocommerce\action-scheduler\classes\ActionScheduler_ActionFactory.php(177): ActionScheduler_HybridStore->save_action(Object(ActionScheduler_Action)) #2 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\wp-content\plugins\wpforms-lite\vendor\woocommerce\action-scheduler\classes\ActionScheduler_ActionFactory.php(84): ActionScheduler_ActionFactory->store(Object(ActionScheduler_Action)) #3 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\wp-content\plugins\wpforms-lite\vendo in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\wp-content\plugins\wpforms-lite\vendor\woocommerce\action-scheduler\classes\migration\ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php on line 44
```